# Java script fetch returns 200 but no data

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I have a requirement to display all the countries in the world in a drop down.
So I found this api end point [END POINT LINK](https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all). When I copy and paste this end point link in my web browser I got a response with all the data. (countries);

When I try to embed this in project.

```js
getCountries() {
      try {
       
        fetch(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all`).then(data =>
          console.log(data)
        );
        
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("HERE ERROR COMES", error);
      }
    }
```

It does go to then block of the fetch method. But gives me the output
[image]

There is nothing called data here. Even I get a success respond.
Why could this happen? Is this something related to cors errors?

Comment: What's in `body`?

Comment: Have you looked at `response.body`? Have you tried `response.json()` ?Does the response have the correct data type? Read the specifications of the fetch API to find which response method is appropriate for whatever the restcountries server returned you. What you call `data` is a Response object. You have to handle that response according to what you are fetching and create the real data object yourself.

Comment: also, this `try...catch` won't do the job ;)

Comment: I think the problem was unlike axios you can't directly access response data in the fetch method. You have to convert it into json and then access it. I marked answer and it worked for me. =) Thank you guys all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use as follow:

```js
let url = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all';

fetch(url)
.then(res => res.json())
.then((data) => {
  console.log(data);
})
.catch(err => { throw err });
```

Comment: is it necessary to throw in catch ? It will be wrapped into `Promise.reject(err)`

Comment: Oh, I don't know about it. This my code is basic using ...

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
function getCountries(){
  fetch("https://api.printful.com/countries ")
  .then((resp) => resp.json()) // Transform the data into json
  .then(function(data) {
     let countries = data.result;
     return countries.map(function(country){
        console.log(country.name);
        //Create your list here
     });
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

responce.type 'cors' probably means Cross Origin Request - and it's blocking it - try to find another api