# Why does javascript fetch() return 403 meanwhile python-requests returns 200?

Tags: javascript, python, amazon-s3, python-requests, fetch

Using S3's generated pre-signed URL, python is able to make the request fine, however, javascript fetch and XMLHttpRequest returns 403 forbidden error whenever data is specified in the body. They are both invoked locally.

Relevant medium articles, fetch documentation, XMLHttpRequest documentation, requests documentation.

python-requests:

```
req = requests.put(url, data='placeholder')
```

JavaScript:

```
fetch(url, {
    method: 'PUT',
    body: 'placeholder'
}
```

JavaScript returns 200 when the body is not specified, however, returns 403 when the body is specified. Python returns status 200 with or without the data parameter.

Comment: Try passing in few headers along with the Javascript request.

Comment: I captured the python request header and it only specified 'Content-Length', to my knowledge this is auto generated in both Fetch and requests. I hardcoded it in Fetch just in case, it returned unsafe header (as expected) and still returned 403

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java script fetch returns 200 but no data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52312991/java-script-fetch-returns-200-but-no-data)

Comment: Try passing the 'Agent' header.

Comment: @SamChats Do you mean 'User-Agent'? What should be the value for the header?

Comment: Yes, use the value as `'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Cafari/537.36'`.

Comment: Still doesn't work :(, I tried APITester and it generated also 'Accept' and 'Host' header as well, I'm guessing that'd be auto-generated in fetch, I tried hard coding it in the header anyway and it still didn't work. Could it be how requests takes in the 'data' parameter and how fetch takes in the 'body' parameter? The link is from APITester with my config and it should work for the next hour, I'm using presigned S3 upload. It works in APITest.
https://www.apitester.com/shared/checks/d2eaed86ddac44c58d37ca66959c4fe9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially the problem was that Javascript fetch auto-generated the header 'Content-Type'. The API Gateway/Lambda that presigned this URL does not expect a 'Content-Type' header, thus JavaScript was erroring out while Python wasn't. I solved it by specifying a Content-Type that was permissible by the Lambda and hard-coded it on the JavaScript side.